# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition is not working in React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

```
   constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          initialPosition: {
                latitude: 0,
                longitude: 0,
                latitudeDelta: 0,
                longitudeDelta: 0,
              }
        }; 
}

      componentDidMount () {
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (position) => {
                var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude);
                var long = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude);


                var initialRegion = {
                    latitude: lat,
                    longitude: long,
                    latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                    longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
                }

                this.setState({ initialPosition: initialRegion});
            },
            (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
            { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
          );
```

My `getCurrentPosition` function isn't working

After I get my current location how can I get my current location's name.

How to fix it?

Comment: Define: "is not working" What happens? What do you expect?

Comment: Didn't you ask this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54176353/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-current-location-in-react-native

Comment: @Andrew now I realized my getCurrentPosition is also not working. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Location

I think you need to read the documentation for how location works in react-native. All the methods that you require for tracking a users location are there.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation

`getCurrentPosition`

> Invokes the success callback once with the latest location info.

This means that it you only get one update for each call to this function. So if you are expecting it to get a continuous stream of updates then you aren't reading the documentation.

`watchPosition`

> Invokes the success callback whenever the location changes.

This means that whenever your device moves location you will get notified and you can update your state with the new location. However, it only updates when you move location. If you don't move location then you won't get updates.

This tutorial will show you how to use the different methods available for location.
https://hackernoon.com/react-native-basics-geolocation-adf3c0d10112

#### Reverse Geocode Lookup

Secondly, to get the name of the current users location based on the GPS coordinates is called a reverse geocode lookup. There currently exist a few packages that do this

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kiwicom/react-native-reverse-geocode

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@binpar/react-native-geocoder

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-geocoder

Some of these are in alpha/beta, some haven't been updated in ages. So your mileage may vary, however you cannot use these packages with Expo.

#### Reverse Geocoding with fetch and google api

You should look at the documentation that google has. 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#reverse

> Reminder: To use the Geocoding API, you must get an API key and you
>   must enable billing. You can enable billing when you get your API key
>   (see the Quick guide) or as a separate process (see Usage and
>   Billing).

This simple function should allow you to perform a reverse geocode lookup you just need to pass the latitude, longitude and your Google API Key

```
async getAddress (latitude, longitude, APIKEY) {
  let url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${latitude},${longitude}&key=${APIKEY}`;
  try {
    let response = await fetch(url);
    let responseJson = await response.json();
    // do what you want with the responseJson here.
    return responseJson
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn(error); 
    // make sure you handle error and return something if an error occurs
  }
}
```

Comment: how can I do it by fetching it from google apis key?

Comment: See my update, but note that using the Geocoding API can cost.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the address and everything you'd like from the google map api.

```
handleAddress = () => {
        const API_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        const {latitude, longitude} = this.props;
        const requestOption = {
            method: 'GET'
        };

        fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${latitude},${longitude}&key=${API_KEY}`, requestOption)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({
                    address: response.results[0].formatted_address});
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.warn(error);
            });
    };
```